# Python2.7: paramiko will not SFTP to port 115. pysftp is successful

Tags: python, paramiko

I thought I'd share this puzzler. . . I've been successfully using 'plain' paramiko for SFTP for years (but always to port 22).  I had a requirement to do SFTP over a non-standard port (115) and I could not establish a connection.

Moving to pysftp solved the problem, but as best I can tell, pysftp is built ontop of the paramiko libraries.

'plain' paramiko code:

```
import paramiko

transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname,115))
transport.connect(username=user,password=passwd)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

The error thrown:

```
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 311, in __init__
'Unable to connect to %s: %s' % (hostname, reason))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: [Errno 10060] 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host 
has failed to respond
```

Moving to pysftp has solved the problem, but pysftp has a paramiko dependency

```
sftp = pysftp.Connection(hostname,username=user,password=passwd,port=115)
```

Insights are appreciated

Comment: Works for me. Try `paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log"); transport = paramiko.Transport(("example.com",80)); transport.connect()` and check the `paramiko.log` - In my case, it's clear that it connected to HTTP server on port 80. -- You rather used a wrong value for `hostname` with Paramiko (you have used `host` in pysftp).

Comment: The same host was used for both examples.  I've edited the original post to reflect this

Comment: Does the code in my comment work for you as expected or not? What version of Paramiko are you using?